# Can I put a single quote in a JQuery attribute equals selector ([attribute=value])?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

My Html looks like this:

```
        <a href="#" id="QuoteTest">Click Here</a>
        <ul>
            <li title="this" style="position:relative">one</li>
            <li title="this" style="position:relative">two</li>
            <li title="tha't" style="position:relative" >three</li>
            <li title="tha't" style="position:relative">four</li>
         </ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$('a#QuoteTest').click(function() {
    $('li[title=this]').animate({ 'left': '+=40px' }, 'slow');
    $("li[title=tha't]").animate({ 'top': '+=40px' }, 'slow');
});
```

I can't get the selector to work with a single quote in it. I tried escaping the quote with a, "\", backslash but that didn't help.

Any ideas on what is proffered way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try two

`$("li[title=tha\\'t]").animate({ 'top': '+=40px' }, 'slow');`

Answer (score 5):

None of these worked for me in IE, so I had to use filter():

```
$("li").filter(function(index){
    return $(this).attr("title") == "tha\'t"; 
})
.animate({ 'top':'+=40px' }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a double backslash, oddly enough. Something about how jQuery escapes those strings. So you'd have:

```
$("li[title=tha\\'t]").animate({ 'top': '+=40px' }, 'slow');
```

That's been the case in other situations. Let me know if that works this time.